# JTable not appearing in Window

Tags: java, user-interface, jtable

I am creating a table containing data from a Neo4j database. The java code is connected to the database and the code is all written correctly imo. The table will also have a progress bar below it. The progress bar appears on the GUI fine but the JTable area is just blank. Here is some code from the class.

```
public class BiogramTable extends JFrame
{

    //*********************************************************************************
    //* CONNECTION TO NEO4J DATABASE BLOCK                                            *
    //*********************************************************************************
    static Driver   driver1     = GraphDatabase.driver( "bolt://localhost", AuthTokens.basic( "****", "*******" ) );
    static Session  session1        = driver1.session();
    static StatementResult  resultVariable1;
    static Record           recordVariable1;

    //Establish the POSTer
    static MaxentTagger tagger1 = new MaxentTagger ("taggers/english-caseless-left3words-distsim.tagger");

    //Create a query object
    static Query neoQuery1 = new Query();   
    static String resultString1 = new String();
    static String POSTedText1   = new String();



    private JProgressBar bar;
    private JTable selectionTable;




     public static void main( String[] arg ) {
            new BiogramTable();
        }

    public BiogramTable() {

        selectionTable = new JTable( new TableModel() );
        ListSelectionModel selec = selectionTable.getSelectionModel();
        selec.addListSelectionListener( new TableSelectionListener() );
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane( selectionTable );
        getContentPane().add( scroll );
        bar = new JProgressBar( 0, 10 );
        bar.setStringPainted( true );
        getContentPane().add( bar, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
        setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        setSize( 300, 300 );
        setVisible( true );
    }

    private class TableModel extends DefaultTableModel {



        DefaultTableModel model=new DefaultTableModel()  
        {
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column)  
            {
                switch(column)
                {
                case 0:                             // |This is the first column
                    return Boolean.class;           // |First column is set to Boolean as it will contain check boxes
                case 1:                             // |This is the second column
                    return String.class;            // |Second column set to String as it will contain strings
                default:
                    return String.class;            // |The table is set to String as default 
                }   
            }
        };

        public TableModel(){

        //Create and run the query in the table         
        neoQuery1= Q1();
        resultVariable1 = session1.run(neoQuery1.get());    

        //resultVariable = session.run(neoQuery.get()); 


        //ASSIGN THE MODEL TO TABLE 
        //selectionTable.setModel(model);

        model.addColumn("Select");                  // |Column for Check boxes
        model.addColumn("Bigrams");                 // |Column for Bigrams


        String values = new String ("");    

        while(resultVariable1.hasNext())                                      
        {   
            recordVariable1 = resultVariable1.next();                       
            values          = recordVariable1.get("w4").asString();  // |This is to add the data from database into table as string variables       
            model.addRow(new Object[]{false, values});               // |Put the data in the table as values
                                                                     // |Notice that false in the value of the check box column

        }   //ENDWHILE      
    }
```

When I run the code This is the result I am getting.

[image: The Results]

In the screenshot you can see that the progress bar is showing but the JTable that should be in the area above is not being displayed.

I have tried this with no luck:

```
getContentPane().add(selectionTable, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies with your TableModel class.

When you create an instance of TableModel, you should then add data to your TableModel.

What you are doing instead is adding your data to a *different* model inside of your TableModel:

`DefaultTableModel model=new DefaultTableModel()`

So when you create a new JTable with your TableModel nothing displays because all of the data is contained inside the DefaultTableModel named model, and not your instance of TableModel.

You do not need the following code:

```
DefaultTableModel model=new DefaultTableModel()  
{
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column)  
    {
        switch(column)
        {
            case 0:                             // |This is the first column
                return Boolean.class;           // |First column is set to Boolean as it will contain check boxes
            case 1:                             // |This is the second column
                return String.class;            // |Second column set to String as it will contain strings
            default:
                return String.class;            // |The table is set to String as default 
        }   
    }
};
```

And instead of

```
model.addColumn("Select");                  // |Column for Check boxes
model.addColumn("Bigrams");                 // |Column for Bigrams
```

You should just add the data to your TableModel instance:

```
addColumn("Select");                  // |Column for Check boxes
addColumn("Bigrams");                 // |Column for Bigrams
```

I don't see why you need to extend DefaultTableModel at all though, the following code would work fine, and is much simpler:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class BiogramTable extends JFrame {

    public BiogramTable() {

        JTable selectionTable = new JTable(
                new Object[][]{
                    { true, "Foo" },
                    { false, "Bar"}
                },
                new Object[]{"Select", "Biagrams"}
        );

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(selectionTable);
        getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar(0, 10);
        bar.setStringPainted(true);
        getContentPane().add(bar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        new BiogramTable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to add data from a query using this method? So instead of Object I wish to use getColumnClass.

Comment: It's fine I have fixed it. Thank you for your help.